# Como carregar dados de uma requisição ajax em DataTables

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-datatables

gostaria de saber uma forma pra carregar dados de um chamada ajax para a datatables.

de forma que eu consiga recarregar a tabela.
estou carregando por um método em ajax que passa para a tabela no objeto data, mas quando chamo o método novamente para recarregar a tabela recebo o erro:

> DataTables warning: table id=imagens - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após uma longa pesquisa consegui resolver o problema. foi só adicionar o seguinte parâmetro na inicialização:

```
 destroy: true
```

fonte: [StackOverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545792/cannot-reinitialise-datatable-dynamic-data-for-datatable)